# How do I insert a javascript in WHM (not cpanel) header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cpanel, whm

I have searched for a way to insert a small jQuery to include in my `WHM` gui header - more specific in `WHM > InstallatronPlugin > InstalledApplications`.

I found in the `cPanel` documentation that it's possible to insert this in the `cPanel` headers. The `cPanel` interface is generally more flexible.

But I need to insert a `jQuery` script in the `WHM` header. I found that I could write a `plugin/module` for `WHM`, but in my mind that's an overkill when all i want is to put one line of js in the header. Off course it would be great if I could put this in some kind of "override" or tweeks directory so it doesn't get overwritten when I update `WHM/cPanel`.

Any input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: connect via ssh to your WHM server and then go to this location:

```
/usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/
```

That's the location where you will find all the WHM scripts, css files etc

Not sure where exactly you should include your jQuery scrpt but at least it might be a starting point!

My suggestion is to ask the exact same question on the cPanel forums. You pay for a cPanel/WHM license so you can always create an account on their forum and ask whatever you want to find out. There is a big number of active users and also the cPanel staff guys will answer your questions.

Comment: /usr/local/cpanel/whostmgr/docroot/ was massive! I could definitely insert some code there, and it would probably work until the next update.
I will ask on the forums too, maybe they know a place to put the js where it's safe from updates :)

Comment: Or you could just save the modified files and then after an update compare the new files with the previous ones... eventually do a diff and see what else  has been modified. You can also set the WHM updates to manual and update WHM when it's really necessary.

Comment: I am glad that I could help. If that's the answer you were looking for please do mark it as the appropiate answer! Thanks